# htaccess , go from sub.domain.com to domanin.com

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I searched the site but did not get it.

I want to change the address

from:
 http://dl.cafecaset.com/pictures/dir1/dir2/dir3/3.jpg

to :
 http://cafecaset.com/pictures/dir1/dir2/dir3/3.jpg

Note: [dir1] and [dir2] and [dir3] and jpg file are dynamic.

And the subdomain([dl].cafecaset.com) for download host  and is separate from the main hosts, but is set to the main domain.

Comment: I think this question is more fitting in www.serverfault.com , try asking over there and probably you'll get an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dl
RewriteRule ^ http://cafecaset.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```